# Property Injection in NancyFx Module

Tags: c#, autofac, nancy, tinyioc

For e.g I have NacyModule like:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule {
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    public HomeModule() {
        Get["/"] = _ => "ok";
    }
}
```

I now about constructor injection, it's work ok, but is there a way to use `property injection` in Nancy Module(TinyIoC, Autofac doesn't matter)?

Comment: Why do you want to use property injection? Using constructor injection is bad practice because property injection leads to [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

Comment: I know about code smell and ect. @Steven, thanks, but I need to use property injection.

Comment: But why do you need property injection?